# My android app is not supported supported on Note 4 and Sony Xperia phones

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

My Manifest runs with this

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
                  android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

But when i upload the apk to play store it shows Samsung Note 4 and Samsung Edge as not supported, anyone know why?

Comment: Can you add more information? What versions are you targeting? What's the minimum version? Are the comparable devices to those two which are showing up as supported?

Comment: Have you tried just leaving out the `<supports-screens>` element entirely? there's no need for it if you want to allow everything...

Comment: I've tried removing `<supports-screens>` but it still doesn't support the HD Phones.

Comment: My support for Android versions are `android:targetSdkVersion="19" android:minSdkVersion="14"/>`  I was reading on forums that i need to change my Display Metrics to support XXHDPI phones, How should i do that?